# squeeze characters in a textbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have strings, e.g.

```
Computer > Software > Programming Language > Python
Computer > Software > Game > BT4
```

I want to squeeze and display like the following, if the string does not fit in the width of textbox:

```
Computer > Software > ...> Python
Computer > Software > Game > BT4
```

The strings are obtained from an AJAX response. How can I achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: I concatnated the strings obtained from ajax response but failed to squeeze them, if the strings length are greater than the textbox maxmimum character length

Comment: @Ejay....alert(concat_strings);

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This might help you solve your problem:</strike>

https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/jquery-ellipsis

or even

http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

**Update**

Here is what I came up with: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYuuZ/)

```
appendList = ['Computer', 'Software', 'Programming Language', 'Python'];
idx = -1;
$('#appendButton').on('click', function() {
    if (idx++ >= appendList.length-1)
        return;
    var inputField = $('#inputField'),
        value = inputField.val();
    inputField.val(value + ((idx == 0) ? appendList[idx]:' > ' + appendList[idx]));
        value = inputField.val();
    // Check the length based on the "size" of the input.
    if (value.length >= 30) {
         // Get the last "section"
        var startPos = (value.lastIndexOf('>')-1),      
            begStr  = value.slice(0, startPos - 1),
            saveStr = value.slice(startPos);

        // Now we need the last occurrence of '>', 
        // This will give you multiple occurrences of '...'
        var secStartPos = begStr.lastIndexOf('>')+2;

        // Or you can use these two lines, instead
        // of the ones below if you only ever want
        // one '...', but to always show the last "section"
        //
        // var secStartPos = begStr.indexOf('>')+2;
        // while ((secStartPos = begStr.lastIndexOf('>', secStartPos)+2) >= 30) { };
        //
        var secSaveStr = begStr.slice(0, secStartPos);

        // Now append '...'
        secSaveStr += '...';

        // Rebuild the string.
        var finalStr = secSaveStr + saveStr;

        inputField.val(finalStr);
    }
});
```

Oh yeah BTW, no clue what this does when the text box fills up with '> ... >' :) GL

Comment: Does this add an ellipsis in the middle of text?

Comment: Not sure, it doesn't look like it.  Are you rendering the crumbs with jQuery?

Comment: Also, looks like the bottom link is a more robust and documented plugin.

Comment: @Drewdiddy611, no these are not breadcrumbs. These are texts that I will append into drop down text box, like in google suggest.

Comment: @user1051068 Updated original answer with an example that might get you moving in the right direction.